# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When the 'clean' command is called

---

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def limpar(ctx, ammount):
    await ctx.send(f'{ammount} are going to be deleted')
    sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=ammount)
```

---

(discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str') is raised
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to type hint the argument `ammount` as an integer:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def limpar(ctx, ammount: int):
     await ctx.send(f'{ammount} are going to be deleted')
#.....rest of the code
```

Comment: you dont have to use `{str(ammount)}` in a format string, you can just use `{ammount}` python will convert it to a string representation of the integer by default.

Comment: @Kejax wasnt sure of this, good to know thx 